# sprintf conversion int to string not working

Tags: printf, type-conversion

Ive alot of different ways to make this conversion work, all have failed. I need to convert 55 to a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    double time = 55;
    char *buffer = ""; //char *buffer; doesnt work either
    sprintf(buffer, "%d\n", time);//without newline doesnt work either
    printf("%s",buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently setting memory that is not yours to `"55\n"`. You have to allocate memory on the stack that you can then modify with the following code (replace your `char *buffer = "";` line):

```
char buffer[4] = { 0 };
```

This is to create enough room for a `'5'`, a `'5'`, a `'\n'`, and a `'\0'`.

Comment: Actually I realized that the problem is that i am using double instead of int. If I use int then it works.